# Jquery / Ajax http header connection close ignored

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, http, connection

Good day,
I have a website that shows realtime data. It updates the DIVS on the page every 30s. It does this by using the JQUERY load function and calling a PHP with the data. Because some browsers cache this, I needed to add a random number to the PHP request so it always updates. Depending on the result it highlights the DIV.

```
        $( "#Wheater_Station_Div" ).load( "Weather_data.php?" + Math.random(), function( response, status, xhr ) {
         if ( status == "error" ) {
          $('.Wheater_ST_col_2').css({'background-color' : 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6)'}).effect("highlight", {color: 'red'}, 1000);
         }else{
               $('.Wheater_ST_col_2').effect("highlight", {color: 'green'}, 1000);  
              }
    });
```

Now about the problem. Above code results in every request opening a new tcp socket/port on the server. When more clients connect a large amount of sockets are idle and on timeout. To avoid leaving the connections open I wanted to set the HTTP header to "Connection: close" instead of the standard "keep alive".

I tried every example I found on internet like using Ajax to change the headers and trying to close the connection from the PHP script. In all cases the connection type never changes and stays on keep alive.

For example below code results in Refused to set unsafe header "Connection"

```
jQuery.ajax({
url: URL,
async: boolVariable,
beforeSend: function(xhr)   
{
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
}   
})
```

The next just gets ignored

```
    $.ajax({
     url: "Weather_data.php?" + Math.random(),
     headers: { 'Connection': 'close' },
    }).done(function(data) { // data what is sent back by the php page
      $('#Wheater_Station_Div').html(data); // display data
      $('.Wheater_ST_col_2').css({'background-color' : 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6)'}).effect("highlight", {color: 'red'}, 1000);
    });
```

Then trying it from the called PHP script using the following also gets ignored

```
ob_end_clean();
header("Connection: close");
ignore_user_abort(true); // just to be safe
ob_start();
echo('Text the user will see');
$size = ob_get_length();
header("Content-Length: $size");
ob_end_flush(); // Strange behaviour, will not work
flush(); // Unless both are called !
// Do processing here 
sleep(30);
echo('Text user will never see');
```

So is there any way to force closing the connection after the script was called? Or should I find a way to reuse the open connection without the problem of some browers using the cache when the links doesn't change.

Here a screenshot of the capture when data updates. JQUERY loads the PHP in a DIV. The outgoing port nr changes on every get request

[See the link for capture lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7sVK.png)

Comment: The server should close idle connections by itself if it gets too many, you don't need to do this in your application.

Comment: And the browser will reuse connections, it won't open a new connection if it has one already opened.

Comment: I understand it will close the idle connections but it seems to take extra ressources. I think in this case the browser doesn't reuse the connections because the request link changes the whole time with "math random". When I check the communication I also see for every update a new TCP port is acquired which indicates a new connection every 30 seconds for every client.

Comment: Adding the random number has nothing to do with whether it reuses the connection. That just keeps it from using the cache. Most requests have different URLs than the previous one, but they still reuse the connection.

Comment: Anyway, connection management is handled internally within the browser and server, it's not something you can control in the application.

Comment: In that case I don't understand why I see a new TCP port created for every update. Can this be triggered by the way JQUERY issues the load function?

Comment: I just tried it with Chrome, and my packet capture showed it using the same connection for each AJAX request.

Comment: I just did the same and added the capture. The website is locate here so you can try it out if possible.

Comment: [link](http://waddendata.nl)

Comment: Your server closes connections that have been idle for 5 seconds. Since you send your AJAX requests every 30 seconds, the old connection is no longer available.